# FabricJS Its there some kind of container or handler data into fabric.object ?

Tags: canvas, containers, fabricjs

Its there some kind of container into fabric.object?

I want to attach JSON string into each fabric.object drawn on canvas, this JSON have some special data to fill a form that refresh information of fields when event clic on fabric.object fire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own container.

```
var obj = fabric.Object();
obj.informations = myJson;
```

Then when exporting toJSON() or toObject(), remember to pass the non standard parameter to the function as first argument:

```
obj.toObject(['informations']);
```

This is applicable to all fabric objects of course, rect, circle, paths, images...

Answer (score 0):

you´re right @asturur I share my code if maybe aid somebody else

```
//create and fabric.object and asigning values

var text = new fabric.Text(
    datasourceJson[i].text), { 
    fontFamily: datasourceJson[i].font,               
    transparentCorners: false,
    padding: 5
    });
//thats the main part of example, on text.container save the data that attach him
    text.container=datasourceJson[i].ObjectJson; 

//to consume data just call the name of our container

     var containerValue=canvas.getActiveObject().container;
     console.log("Thats the value saved it: "+containerValue);
```

Comment: you should accept the answer if you think is right. regards.